# How do we generalise a specialised case in physics?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, models

I have come across this sort of thing a lot of times in my textbook. I give the examples below-

> Eg.1-
>
> In the case of a capacitor connected across an alternating current generator, we find $V_c=I_c\times X_c$. Now, the book says, although we found this relation for a special case (as given in a figure in the book) ,it applies to *any* capacitance in any AC circuit.

My question is, how are we so confident that it holds everywhere by just doing one specific example?

> Eg 2.-
>
> We find energy density of an electric field is given by $\frac12\epsilon_0E^2$. Now, the book says, although we find this for the special case of the electric field of a parallel plate capacitor, this holds true for any source of electric field.

How do we know that it holds everywhere, by just doing one special case? Is there any underlying principle that allows us to extend such theories in physics?

These are just two random examples. There are innumerable other cases where we derive something for a specialised example and extend it to a generalised case.

Answer (score 2):

You *don't* know that these relations hold everywhere by just doing one example. Your textbook is simply informing you, without proof, that they do hold everywhere.

Comment: How do we know it holds everywhere? We cannot do for infinite number of cases one by one, isn't it?

Comment: @tatan Within the context of a theory you can prove the general case, it just involves more mathematical sophistication that doing a specific case. Your first example is essentially [Thévenin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem), for instance.